# SU Retag request: bootup & booting -> boot

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

It seems kinda redundant to have *booting* and *boot* separate; although one is a verb and one is a noun, it seems like it would be simpler to keep them under one tag (for organization's sake).

I'm suggesting *bootup* (3) & *booting* (49) -> **boot** (343)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done.

[multi-boot] and [dual-boot] also need to be merged, but I'm not sure which one needs to be kept.

Much like the more-than-one-monitor tags ([dual-monitors] and [multiple-monitors], which were merged into [multiple-monitors]), we really don't need two different tags for the concept of "more than one".  I think [multiple-monitors] works pretty well, and I'd prefer to keep [multi-boot] as the more general term.  But I'm afraid [dual-boot] is more common and more widely-known.

Comment: Is it possible that `[multi-boot]` and `[dual-boot]` should be kept separated? To me, `[multi-boot]` refers to 3+ bootable OSes. `[dual-boot]` is by far more common both in term and function. There are only 3 questions tagged with both, so it may be a pretty quick cleanup.

Comment: I think that when the tag auto-suggestor (or whatever it's designed to be) comes out, `[dual-boot]` should be auto-corrected to `[multi-boot]` so users don't have to think about it. For now, I'd support the moving of `[dual-boot]` to `[multi-boot]`. The prefix *multi-* means *more than one*, and dual- means *two*. Last time I checked, `2 < 1`. My 2¢

Comment: @Jon: you're correct that that's what those mean.  but for categorization purposes, questions that apply to 2 OS's generally get answers that also apply to 3+ OS's.  there's no need for 2 separate categories.

Comment: @thepurplepixel: funny, last i checked, `2 > 1`.  remember, the alligator eats the bigger number first.

Comment: @quack: Good point -- I like thepurplepixel's plan for tag synonyms on these, though I think you'll have a hard time keeping `[dual-boot]` out of the system if they're merged now. Also, LOL -- I thought I was the only one who was taught the alligator method for > and <.

Comment: @quack: excuse my inequalities; my brain tends to turn off on weekends :)